# adding image icons in blackberry tree view

Tags: blackberry, treeview, bitmap

I have designed a simple tree view in blackberry java app.Now i need to add add an image in the child node.

is it possible?

Comment: you can use drawBitmap method  in TreeFieldCallback to draw icon.

Comment: can you please send me some code.

Answer (score 0):

Find this code

```
class TreefieldDemoScreen extends MainScreen
{
    public TreefieldDemoScreen()
    {             
        setTitle("Tree Field with icon");
        String parentNode =  new String("Parent");
        String firstChild =  new String("first child");
        String secondChild =  new String("second child");
        String thirdChild =  new String("third child");

        TreeCallback myCallback = new TreeCallback();
        TreeField myTree = new TreeField(myCallback, Field.FOCUSABLE);

        int node2 = myTree.addChildNode(0, parentNode);
        myTree.addChildNode(node2, firstChild);
        myTree.addChildNode(node2, secondChild);
        myTree.addChildNode(node2, thirdChild);
        add(myTree);
    }

    private class TreeCallback implements TreeFieldCallback 
    {
        public void drawTreeItem(TreeField _tree, Graphics g, int node, int y, int width, int indent) 
        {
            String text = (String)_tree.getCookie(node); 
            Bitmap b=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon_bb copy.png");
            g.drawText(text, indent+b.getWidth(), y);

            g.drawBitmap(indent, y, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), b, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```